# Theory to compress a random stream

Tags: compression, theory

In Theory, if a byte stream is randomized, high Kolmogorov entropy it can not be compressed. In light of the first statement and in theory, if that same stream can be mapped through a reversable permutation algorithm which changes its entropy, then compressed, then restored, compression would be possible?

Such as this hand permutation scheme that also can be implemented in a cipher. In the photo attached, i changed the entropy in step four to seven 1s from 1,5,3,4,1,2,2, > 1,1,1,1,1,1,1

Here is a video where i show the method by hand. I use this in another video to encrypt data.... by hand

https://youtu.be/thS2-hJJkSs

Please comment after seeing video.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belong on cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: If seven random numbers have no sequences and can not be compressed those numbers require 56 bits, but a transform permutation of those 7 numbers can transform them to seven 1's that can be compressed. A simple number that represents how many times those numbers were run through the permutation transform. Reverse the process to restore the stream. a max of 13 bits making a compression of 76% on random numbers. The question is what mapping program am I referring to?

Comment: You may have permutted the ordering but not the data. A permutation of random data is still random data--even if it is reversible.

Comment: Both order and data were transformed in this reversible "permutation transform". Unfortunately I am not a programmer. It was a project that Kelly D. Crawford, Ph.D and I worked on for over 8 years. He passed away just as the work was being finished. He was the programmer and I was the imagination to come up with ideas outside the box. The only reason I am pursuing this is it give posthumous credit to his work and mine.

Comment: I think I understand your scheme is this: transform a sequence of random bytes using some function. Repeat this transformation a number of times N until you get a sequence that has low entropy and then compress it. Use the compressed data and the number to uncompress the data by applying the inverse transformation to the uncompressed raw form. If I have understood the scheme right, I think where this must fail is that the average size of (compressed data) + (number of iterations) is going to be as big as the original byte stream, in the long run. Some will be shorter, some longer.

Comment: Yes, I am horrible at explaining things so that they are clearly understood. One important detail. I can reduce the number of permutations with repeats to only include a compressible set of the first number. Example. If I want to reduce a random set 1,5,3,4,1,2,2, I only need to find the iteration of the first digit with repeats. In this example I am looking for 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 using the permutation algorithm it is the 4th loop. I can express 1,5,3,4,1,2,2, as a single 4 Now I take the next set of 7 and repeat the process. Inverse process to decompress.

Comment: Please explain how you come from 7 times 1 to 1,5,3,4,1,2,2. How exactly should the permutation algorithm work?

Comment: Can I post this new scheme here?

Comment: sure or answer, edit youre question to add more detail

Comment: Video added as an edit to explain.